# The hash table probability

Tags: hash, hashtable, probability

I still confuse how to find hash table probability. I have hash table of size 20 with open addressing uses the hash function

hash(int x) = x % 20

How many elements need to be inserted in the hash table so that the probability of the next element hitting a collision exceeds 50%.

I use birthday paradox concerns to find it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem and seems get an incorrect answer. Where is my mistake? 
[calculating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67k8B.jpg)

> 1/2=1-e^(-n^2/(2*20))
>   ln(1/2)=ln(e)*(-n^2/40)
>   -0.69314718=-n^2/40
>   n=scr(27.725887)=5.265538

Answer (score 0):

> How many elements need to be inserted in the hash table so that the probability of the next element hitting a collision exceeds 50%.

Well, it depends on a few things.

The simple case is that you've already performed 11 inserts with distinct and effectively random integer keys, such that 11 of the buckets are in use, and your next insertion uses another distinct and effectively random key so it will hash to any bucket with equal probability: clearly there's only a 9/20 chance of that bucket being unused which means your chance of a collision during that 12th insertion exceeds 50% for the first time.  This is the answer most formulas, textbooks, people etc. will give you, as it's the most meaningful for situations where hash tables are used with strong hash functions and/or prime numbers of buckets etc. - the scenarios where hash tables shine and are particularly elegant.

Another not-uncommon scenario is that you're putting say customer ids for a business into the hash table, and you're assigning the customers incrementing id numbers starting at 1.  Even if you've already inserted customers with ids 1 to 19, you know they're in buckets `[1]` to `[19]` with no collisions - your hash just passes the keys through without the mod kicking in.  You can then insert customer 20 into bucket `[0]` (after the mod operation) without a collision.  Then, the 21st customer has 100% chance of a collision.  (But, if your data's like this, please use an array and index directly using the customer id, or customer_id - 1 if you don't want to waste bucket [0].)

There are many other possible patterns in the keys that can affect when you exceed a 50% probability of a collision: e.g. all the keys being odd or multiples of some value, or being say ages or heights with a particular distribution curve.

The mistake with your use of the Birthday Paradox is thinking it answers your question.  When you put "1/2" and "20" into the formula, it's telling you that the point at which your ***cumulative*** probability of a collision reaches 1/2, but your question is "the probability of the ***next*** element hitting a collision exceeds 50%" (emphasis mine).